# Clean Image Attachment for OCR in Ruby-On-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, ocr

How can I use a script such as [Textcleaner](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/) within a Ruby-On-Rails application?  Currently I'm using a custom paperclip processor where I use parameters similar to the script.  Here is the has_attached_file line in my ActiveRecord:

```
  has_attached_file :file, :style=> { :processors => [:text_cleaner] } }
```

Here is the Paperclip Processor:

```
module Paperclip
  # Handles grayscale conversion of images that are uploaded.
  class TextCleaner< Processor

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end

    def make
      src = @file
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])
      dst.binmode

      begin
        parameters = []
        parameters << ":source"
        parameters << "-auto-orient"
        parameters << "-colorspace Gray"
        #parameters << "-sharpen 0x1"
        #parameters << "-type grayscale"
        #parameters << "-contrast-stretch 0"
        #parameters << "-clone 0"
        #parameters << "-deskew 40%"
        parameters << ":dest"

        parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(" ").strip.squeeze(" ")

        success = Paperclip.run("convert", parameters, :source => "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]", :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))
      rescue PaperclipCommandLineError => e
        raise PaperclipError, "There was an error during the grayscale conversion for #{@basename}" if @whiny
      end

      dst
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? It helps to show us your attempts so we tell if you were going about it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using paperclip I was able to add a Text Cleaner processor.  I added it as a style in model via:

```
has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :clean => { :processors => [:text_cleaner] } }
```

And in /lib/paperclip_processors/text_cleaner.rb I have:

```
module Paperclip
  # Handles grayscale conversion of images that are uploaded.
  class TextCleaner < Processor

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end

    def make
      src = @file
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename,@format])

      dst.binmode

      begin
        parameters = '-respect-parenthesis \( :source -colorspace gray -type grayscale -contrast-stretch 0 \) \( -clone 0 -colorspace gray -negate -lat 15x15+5% -contrast-stretch 0 \) -compose copy_opacity -composite -fill "white" -opaque none +matte -deskew 40%  -auto-orient -sharpen 0x1 :dest'
        success = Paperclip.run('convert', parameters, :source => File.expand_path(@file.path), :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))
      rescue PaperclipCommandLineError => e
        raise PaperclipError, "There was an error during the textclean conversion for #{@basename}" if @whiny
      end

      dst
    end

  end
end
```